# Makefile in Windows

Tags: c, windows, makefile

I have a folder named `'X'`. In `X` I have two subfolders: `src` and `include`.

The `src` folder contains a C file `main.c`, and the `include` folder contains a file `main.h`.

I want to write a makefile to build these files(from folder `X`) in windows command prompt.
I have tried a lot but with no effect.
First of all I need the make file format in Linux for this, and once I have that i will do that in Windows.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following links, in there you'll find the format, and basically all that you need to build your Makefile:

http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/

http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm

http://oucsace.cs.ohiou.edu/~bhumphre/makefile.html

Comment: None of these links discuss using make in windows.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've made your Makefile, you can use MinGW's mingw32-make - A Windows native build of GNU make.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the folder (`X`) in file explorer.
2. Right click anywhere > new > text document.
3. Right click on the file > rename > remove `.txt` extension.
4. Open up the makefile with your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NMake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference), which is the windows alternative do Linux make. It is a command-line tool included with Visual Studio.

Although the syntax is very similar, you will find some differences. So the makefile that works on Linux may not work directly with NMake in windows.

In Linux, these lines for example:

```
gcc -c main.cpp -o main.o
gcc -o app main.o -lstdc++
```

In Windows, probably should be changed to:

```
cl.exe /c main.cpp /Fomain.o
link.exe /OUT:app.EXE main.o
```

So the makefile require edition to work with NMAKE in windows.

To use the makefile "as is", you should try a tool to mimic Linux commands in Windows, like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).